# How to compare and store the list number into a variable

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop

I'm trying to get the list number every time the dataValue equals the data. I want to get the number that would show up in the [] in the data variable. Is this possible?

```
for x in data:
   if dataValue == x:
   #gets the current array number and stores it
```

Comment: The usual idiom for this is `for index, x in enumerate(data):` - `index` is the number you're looking for.

Comment: You seem to be looking for the `index` method.  Please refer to  your tutorial on lists.  `my_store = data.index(x)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a reference counter would deliver the data you are looking for.

Example:

```
i = 0
positions = []
for x in data:
  if x == dataValue:
    positions.append(i)
  i++
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension, to get a list of indices:

```
indices = [index for index, x in enumerate(data) if x == dataValue]
```